# Doctrine 2 custom function other schema or package

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get Doctrine to work with Oracle PL/SQL functions, but this also applies to stored functions in other schemas. I do know how to create a custom DQL function. But when calling a package function, the name has a dot in it, e.g. `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(s1, s2)`. I cannot get Doctrine to parse this. I modified the `parse` function from the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) like so:

```
$parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
$parser->match(Lexer::T_DOT);
$parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
$parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
$this->firstDateExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
$parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
$this->secondStringExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
$parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
```

But it just won't recognize the function. Can I make this work somehow? Or am I stuck with native queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a dumb dumb. You have to specify the package name only in the `getSql` method, like so:

```
public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    return \sprintf(
        'UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(%s, %s)',
        $this->firstStringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
        $this->secondStringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker)
    );  
}
```

And then use the function without the `UTL_MATCH` prefix in DQL.